# Jenkins ignores Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a branch [with example `Jenkinsfile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#creating-a-jenkinsfile) on Bitbucket. I have `Jenkins` installed on my linux box. I can create projects via web interface. Particularly, I can specify `Freestyle project` and inside it I can specify branch. I can add build steps on web interface and it will checkout branch and execute steps. But it will take it from web interface, not from `Jenkinsfile`.

Or I can create `Pipeline` type of project. In this case I am unable to specify branch, only repository `URL`. If I run the project, it doesn't even checkout.

How to activate `Jenkinsfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the [Git Parameter Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/), which will allow you to specify the branch to build in your Pipeline project.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58917601/image2018-9-20_22-0-7.png?version=1&modificationDate=1537473611000&api=v2]

That way, you can associate your Jenkinsfile to the right branch to build.

Comment: I have this plugin installed. This UI appears only in `Freestyle Project`. But even when it appears, it ignores `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: @Dims Then all I have left is https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm, which states "When you update the designated repository, a new build is triggered, as long as the Pipeline is configured with an SCM polling trigger.". You do have an SCM polling trigger?